# Creating a DateTime from a string

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a DateTime with HH:MM:SS + Current Date

```
string myTime = "08:50:00";
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.date;
```

The result should be DateTime with combined this information.
How to do ?

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting so I can improve my question

Comment: @GibboK "**This question does not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.Parse(myTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `ParseExact` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

So:

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(myTime,"hh:mm:ss",provider);
```

It should use the current date for the date part.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myDateTimeString;  
DateTime dt;   
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(myDateTimeString); 
Response.Write(dt.Day + "/" + dt.Month + "/" + dt.Year);
```

see http://www.ezineasp.net/post/C-Convert-String-to-DateTime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
  const string myTime = "08:50:00";
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  string[] split = myTime.Split(':');
  DateTime dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, int.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]), int.Parse(split[2]));
```

But you should add some null-checking and other validations.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myTime = "08:50:00";
                DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
               string myDateTime = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}", currentDateTime.Year, currentDateTime.Month, currentDateTime.Day,
                              myTime);

               DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(myDateTime, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));

                //or
                DateTime myNewDatetime = new DateTime(currentDateTime.Year, currentDateTime.Month, currentDateTime.Day,
                                                      8, 50, 0);
```